# WebStorm: How to trigger a Less compilation only on the main.less file while watching multiple files?

Tags: less, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a `.less` files directory with:

- main.less (just import the dependencies)
- dep1.less
- dep2.less
- etc.

I want that modifying a dependency triggers the compilation of the `main.less` file ONLY.

For now here is my configuration in WebStorm Less watcher. What scope and arguments I need?

[image]

Comment: There is a checkbox just for that -- `Track only root files` -- have you tried it?

Comment: It does not change anything. It compils all files individually in ../css

Comment: note that my scope watchs the entire folder (to watch all the changes)

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Documentation says the same -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/new-watcher-dialog.html?search=file%20watcher

Comment: do you also scope the entire folder ?

Comment: Here is screenshot of my settings: https://postimg.org/image/typ365koz/ (It's 2016.3 EAP build, so it looks a bit different; but this project uses the same File Watcher settings for the last 2 years)

Comment: Possibly it depends on how you import those include/partial files -- maybe IDE cannot recognize such inclusion properly but actual compiler does it just fine. **P.S.** Another project using 2016.2 version -- https://postimg.org/image/v5wtuy7lh/ **P.P.S.** Try deleting existing File Watcher and re-creating it from scratch -- might help

Comment: Yes! It works with your last exemple. I uncheck 'create output file from stdout' and put ` ../$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` in the argument. Thx you very much.

Comment: Great! Please post your final solution as an answer (you can accept own answers) -- it will be useful for other users in similar situation (question with accepted answer will be more visible).

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @LazyOne comments I manage to find the right settings.

- set the watch scope to the entire folder
- put `../$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` at the end of less command arguments
- uncheck `Create output file from stdout` causing empty output file (don't know why)
- check `Track only root files`. Which is not very explicit in my case. Indeed it does not really watch the root file but all the `@import` dependencies and **ONLY COMPILE THE ROOT FILE**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped me alot.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefix your partial files with an underscore

```
(_dep1.less,_dep2.less)
```

they wont be compiled. And that doesn't even effect how you call them: @import _dep1.less will import _dep1.less.